# "Cannot open display" error when trying to install JBoss on Linux

Tags: linux, jboss

I am unable to install JBoss on a Linux VM virtual box.

I'm getting this error:

```
$ java -jar jboss-eap-6.2.0-installer.jar

(.:1616): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The EAP installer has a graphical interface. It looks as if your Linux VM either doesn't have an X desktop, or you are logging into it using something other than an X session. To use the graphical installer you will need to run it from a shell within an X desktop (in which case you might just need to set do `export DISPLAY=:0.0` or something similar); or you'll need to take some other convoluted steps to get X running and be able to run executables against the X server.

If you can't run an X desktop, or don't want to, I believe EAP is available as a zipfile you can just unpack.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a value for the DISPLAY variable, e.g. in my case
Microknoppix:~$ echo $DISPLAY 
:0